# Possible Interview Java .equals

Tags: java, string, equals

why is `"".equals(someString);` safer than `someString.equals("");`?

I understand that for example if `someString` is initialized to `null` then the second gives a null pointer exception while the first will run. Is this the only advantage?

Comment: I think so... preventing Null Pointer Exceptions.

Comment: That is the only advantage I'm aware of.  It should also be noted however that this can make your code a little less stable because a value of null for a String can indicate a deeper problem in some situations.  The "safer" approach outlined above will not give you any indication when this problem exists.